# slow Grunt and compass while filling up the .scss file

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

just one question about filling up the .scss file with Grunt and compass. While filling it up, I noticed that it is a bit slow.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for slow compile time when working with a Sass workflow.

1. **Too Many Imports:** If you use a lot of dynamic imports (i.e. Sass Globbing) on many of your _scss files it can slow Sass down as Ruby is doing quite a lot of calculations. You will probably have to kill Sass Globbing all together and manually import individual _scss files, which would be better.
2. **Compiling Too Many Files:** If you have configured your project to generate multiple style sheets (ie: no query, different layouts) this will really clog up your compilation time.
3. **Ruby is Slow:** I run a Windows, so Ruby is notoriously slower then *nix systems and Macs. If Ruby is out of date, update it.
4. **You .sass-cache isn't warm:** There should be a .sass-cache folder when you compile code. If there isn't for some odd reason then Sass would be generating for the first time, everytime.
5. **Disable Compass (technically, Ruby):** If you aren't absolutely dependant on Compass (i.e. you aren't using Singularity/Susy, not using Globbing or Source Maps) then you really don't need it. Scrap it for LibSass which can be installed via `npm install --save-dev grunt-sass`. You could use Bourbon + Bitters as an alternative for compass. LibSass is lightning fast so if speed is a priority, make the switch.